# Como fixar os botões no AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Estou tendo um problema em relação aos botões criados no AlertDialog.
Estou fazendo um APP de frases e em certos momentos as frases são muito grandes e faz com que os botões no AlertDialog desçam.
É possível fixar esses botões?
Aqui segue um exemplo do que acontece:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/ykk010cb8jcb6v5/Screenshot_20170607-111014.png

O meu código é esse:

```
// ALERT DIALOG


                    //atributo da classe.

                    //Cria o gerador do AlertDialog
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FraseAutorFrase.this);
                    builder.setTitle("O que deseja fazer?");//define o titulo
                    builder.setMessage("\nFrase: " + frasesR [position]);//define a mensagem
                    builder.setView(checkBoxView);

                    //define um botão como positivo
                    builder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                        }
                    });

                    //define um botão como compartilhar
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Compartilhar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, frasesR[position] );
                            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                            startActivity(sendIntent);
                        }
                    });

                    alerta = builder.create();//cria o AlertDialog
                    alerta.show();//Exibe
```

Muito Obrigado!!!

Comment: Porque você não cria um scroll na frase?

Comment: Tente inserir seu código a sua pergunta. Isso aumenta a chance de você ter uma resposta mais precisa.

Comment: Oi, Luiz.
Não saberia como implementar o Scroll, na verdade vi uma alternativa que teria que mudar o layout, mas vou tentar.

Comment: Obrigado, Aclay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode construir um layout customizado e colocar dentro dele um ScrollView

mensagem_dialog.xml

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mensagem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

e depois na sua Activity vc "infla" esse layout e insere na no dialog

```
LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mensagem_dialog, null);

TextView textview=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mensagem);
textview.setText("\nFrase: " + frasesR [position]);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
alertDialog.setTitle("O que deseja fazer?");  
alertDialog.setView(view);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", null);  
AlertDialog alert = alertDialog.create();
alert.show();
```

Você pode adaptar o layout e inserir o checkbox pra contemplar o favoritos, o legal que você vai ter total controle do layout :D

Comment: Olá, Milton.
Muito Obrigado pela resposta.
Eu não testei o código ainda, mas vi que declarou um Textview, no meu código não possui TextView, ela já pega as informações de um Array pelo setMessage.
Esse código só funciona com Textview?
Obrigado.

Comment: Na verdade o textview ta nesse outro layout mensagem_dialog que vc infla e injeta no AlertDialog, nele sim vai ter um textview pra exibir a sua mensagem

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!